# Nice Isomorphic Question and way of finding Quickly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I see a question about Isomorphic Graph. the question is:

The first line graph is not isomorphic with which one in the second line?

How we can find isomorphic graph without knowing some geometry map (like rotate or ...)?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest method would be to recognize the given graph as a pentagon with two non-adjacent vertices connected (since a $5$-pointed star is isomorphic to a simple $5$-cycle; a pentagon). The connection isn't a single edge, but an edge that's been turned into two edges by putting a point in the middle.

You can identify that three of the four graphs can be constructed in this same manner.

[image]

Alternatively, the $4$th graph in the second row is the only one with a $6$-cycle, but that's a little harder for me to see, personally.

Answer (score 4):

All the graphs have two vertices of order three and four of order two. The last graph has the two order three vertices connected by an edge, while the rest do not. It is therefore not isomorphic to any other. I have not shown that the rest are isomorphic, but this is enough for the question.

Comment: if you learn something new to others, it's nice ! you re expert and very nice person, and you think enough, but i couldn't get it. if is's not waste your valuable time, please add more detail :)

Comment: One way graphs can fail to be isomorphic is to have different degree sequences-a different number of vertices of each order.  These examples are constructed to pass that test.  Each one has two order three vertices.  The one on the left has them on the left and right and there is no single edge between them.  If you look at the original one and the two in the middle, you can also find the two order three vertices and see there is no single edge between them.  The one on the right has the order three vertices at the top and bottom, the central edge connects them.  Therefore it is not isomorphic

Answer (score 0):

Current algorithms do not solve graph isomorphism efficiently in the worst case.  The best result is an algorithm due to Babai, Kantor and Luks that runs in $2^{O(\sqrt{n \log n})}$ time [Babai, Kantor and Luks, Computational complexity and the classification of finite simple groups, 1983].

If you don't care about the worst case, there are heuristic algorithms that work for all but an exponentially small proportion of graphs in linear time.  See [Practical graph isomorphism II, McKay and Piperno, 2013].